# Movie where some teens find alien armor in the woods

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Looking for the name of a movie where some teens find alien armor in the woods, and put the armor on. One the boots, one the helmet, and one some kind of firearm or glove. And then at the end, they fight with an enemy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this movie, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, roughly how many kids were there in the scene you described?

Comment: Hi! Have a look at [these tips on how to write good story ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), then click [edit] and add as much detail as you can. The more you add, the more likely someone can help you find the movie you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ***[Lazer Team](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3864024/)*** (2015).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazer_Team):

> *Lazer Team* is a 2015 American science fiction action comedy film directed, produced, and co-written by Matt Hullum. The first feature film produced by Rooster Teeth, it stars Burnie Burns, Gavin Free, Michael Jones, Colton Dunn, Allie DeBerry, and Alan Ritchson. The film follows the Lazer Team, a group of four who find themselves responsible for the fate of the planet upon discovering an alien crash site containing a battle suit.

> In 1977, the government has secretly decoded a transmission, sent by the alien Antareans, which warns of a deadly race known as the Worg, coming to destroy Earth. To help defend Earth, the Antareans have sent a powerful battle suit for the "Champion of Earth" to wear, and the government begins training a boy named Adam from birth to be the Champion. Thirty-eight years later, Officer Anthony Hagan arrests Zach Spencer for causing trouble at a party and begins to drive him away, only to find Woody Johnson and Herman Mendoza shooting off unauthorized fireworks. Herman defiantly launches a massive rocket which strikes an incoming UFO and causes it to crash nearby.
>
> **The UFO opens to reveal the battle suit, and the four men each take a piece of it.** The suit activates when all four pieces are worn, and each piece becomes irreversibly and genetically locked to its wearer. They discover **Zach's arm-cannon can shoot energy projectiles, Hagan's gauntlet can create an energy field, Woody's helmet increases his intelligence over time, and Herman's boots can make him run at superhuman speeds.**
>
> [...]
>
> **The Worg warrior arrives in an identical suit of armor.** Woody intercepts a transmission from the ship, revealing that rather than a war they are part of an elimination tournament where the Antareans destroy the losers' planets until one remains. Lazer Team proves unsuccessful at defeating the Worg by themselves, so Adam begins a distraction using riot gear from the police car. Adam is killed by the Worg with a dark matter beam, indirectly teaching the team how to achieve this with the suit. **Lazer Team and the Worg fire dark matter beams into each other, creating a vortex. The four separated suit pieces malfunction and Lazer Team is blown clear of the forcefield, but the Worg and the Antarean ship are consumed.** The team is greeted by a huge crowd outside. Emory arrives and states that the war isn't over, and that Lazer Team is going into space.